# Facebook Graph API - deleting a comment on a page review/ rating

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know if its possible to delete a Facebook comment I made to a facebook review.

I was successful with getting a comment list of a "page review/ rating" with their IDs, and also posting a comment to a "page review/ rating" by reading documentation and going through other threads here. but now stuck with this.

I tried sending DELETE request to [https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{commentID}](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/%7BcommentID%7D) and received this message.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported delete request. Object with ID '{commentID}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

Which makes me wonder if this is not possible via graph API.

above request was made with valid bearer token (page access token, also tried with user access token as well) and the commentID was obtained from the [https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{reviewID}/comments](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/%7BreviewID%7D/comments)